# jquery slide menu over canvas element

Tags: jquery, canvas

I have a canvas where there is continues animation been generated.

I would like a jquery slidemenu going on top of the canvas.

The issues is that the javascript of the canvas keep on writing on top of the jquery slidemenu. How to solve this?

Any input would be very appreciated, many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you use z-index, you'd better change the position

how about

```
<div style="z-index: 2; position: relative;" id="menu">
.....
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Without providing some code it's anyones guess.

Mine is that you need to set a higher `z-index` to the menu element.

```
<canvas style="z-index: 1" /> // I'm on bottom
<ul id="menu" style="z-index: 2">...</ul> // I'm on top
```

Comment: Hi Marko, Thanks for the feedback ~ Here an example. http://my.ofs.edu.sg/user/e_vandeputte/trig/sliding-canvas3.html